# Словообразование: суффикс -ырь-

Tags: этимология, словообразование, заимствования, суффиксы

В словаре Брокгауза и Ефрона утверждается, что русское слово **богатырь** имеет тюркоязычное происхождение. В качестве одного из аргументов приводится якобы отсутствие суффикса **-ырь-** в русском языке:

> > От слова "богат-" не может происходить "богатырь", так как нет суффикса -ырь.

Но на ум приходят такие слова, как **пустырь** (от слова "пустой"), **поводырь** (от "поводья", "на поводу"), **снегирь** (от слова "снег"), **глодырь** (о нем упоминается в словаре Фасмера, от "глодать"), **пузырь** ("пузатый"), **упырь** (Фасмер приводит несколько вариантов этимологии, но все они связаны со славянским происхождением), **пастырь** (от "пасти", "пасу"), **волдырь** и **нетопырь** (у Фасмера говорится о славянском происхождении). Есть просторечное **сырь** (от "сырой").
Пришедшие из европейских языков (греческий, латинский, немецкий) слова тяготеют к такому окончанию: штырь, лодырь, монастырь, пластырь, панцирь, псалтырь и так далее.

В связи с этим вопрос. Насколько правомерно говорить, что такого суффикса в русском языке нет и не было, что такое "окончание" слов для русского языка чуждо, нехарактерно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Ефремовой даются два варианта с этим суффиксом:

А) вести - поводырь (префиксально-суффиксальный способ, ПО + ЫРЬ со значением лицо, характеризующееся действием)

Б) пустой - пустырь (суффиксальный способ, суффикс ЫРЬ со значением пространства, характеризующегося признаком).

Сырь - это нулевая суффиксация.

Comment: Про "сырь" понятно, просто я говорил и в целом про "окончание" (не в смысле морфемы) слов на -ырь-, не только про суффикс.

 То есть такой суффикс все же есть? Почему так мало слов с ним? Возможно ли то, что он перешел в -арь- или -ирь-?

Comment: У Шанского:Пузырь - исконное, суф. производное от пузо. Волдырь - скорее всего, суф. производное (суффикс ЫРЬ)от водлый - водяной. Получается, что суффикс был раньше и выделяется в современном языке. Суффикс АРЬ часто встречается, он многозначный,а вот ИРЬ в современном языке не выделяется.

Comment: То есть неправомерно заявление в словаре Брокгауза и Ефрона. Что ж, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Да вы все уперлись в суффиксы, а это искусственное понятие, насажденное лингвистами. И все-таки это корни, сильно поврежденные как дурным произношением, так и временем. Потому и надо рассматривать суффиксы как корни, а не приставку к слову без всякого смысла, и связывать это надо исключительно не с влиянием первого попавшегося на ум совпадения.
Богатырь — рыцарь, а он участвует в турнирах-схватках, не в цирковом представлении, а в бою... Это ТУР.
Тур — это бык, мощный, сильный. Самцы туров устраивали жуткие схватки во время гона.
Турнир — подражание этим схваткам, а тур — сама схватка-соревнование.
Тот самый тур в слове **богатуръ** с ятью на конце.
А бог, потому что божий человек — монах. ПЕРЕСВЕТ, ОСЛЯБЯ — монахи-богатыри. И решался исход по божьей воле, кому бог помогал, так именно считали.
А что касается окончаний в словах типа *пастырь* — совсем другая «разница».
Это слово пошло от иностранного слова (латынь) *пастор*, а из него сделали в качестве общего подражания *пастырь*. Со словом *пасти* — никакой связи, долой фасмеров.
Зато пастор имеет глубокую связь с этим словом. Но это требует и более развернутого анализа. С каждым подобным словом и «суффиксом».

Answer (score 0):

А слово "колбаса" произошло от слова "колба" или от слова "колобок"? А все современные монголы даже и не знают, что их слово "багатур" и имя "Багатур", оказывается, произошли от слова "богатырь", а переняли они его оттого, что они очень уважали русских богатырей, ну а потом и другие тюркоязычные народы переняли его от монголов...

Comment: Слово"богат" краткое прилагательное. Приведите один пример краткого прилагательного с добавлением суффикса ырь,например: красив-красивырь,хрупок-хрупокырь,ленив-ленивырь и так далее,так, чтобы после добавления этого суффикса речь шла бы о человеке.

Comment: Перечитайте мой пост. Там идет речь конкретно о существовании суффикса -ырь-. Он есть? Выяснили, что есть. Вопрос закрыт. Что еще вам надо?

 Что касается "богат". Причем тут "богат"? Почему нельзя, например, рассмотреть вариант происхождения от глагола "богатеть"? Например, слова "глодырь" и "пастырь", возможно, образовались от глаголов "глодать" и "пасти".

Comment: Суффиксы добавляются к определенным формам,а не к самим глаголам,как я понимаю. Когда  предки говорили ,что слово "богатырь" произошло от слова"багатур", они основывались на факты ,они жили с монголами и знали ,что перенимали,а сегодня люди стали фантазировать.И перечитайте,пожалуйста, мои ответы,я не говорил , что нет суффикса ырь.Я не понимаю,что Вам не нравится. Ведь Вы говорили про суффикс ,а я про происхождение слова.

Comment: Это какие ж такие предки, жившие бок о бок с монголами, вам рассказали про происхождение слова "богатырь"? Имена, пожалуйста.

 Что значит "не к самим глаголам"? Что за "определенные формы"?

 Зачем вы говорите про происхождение слова (причем с нахрапом и передергиванием), если речь о другом?

Comment: Вы меня не поняли,я хочу сказать .что если слово не зарегистрировано в первых словарях .значит оно является иностранным,Как же получилось .что оно зарегистрировано как иностранное,значит предками упоминалось об его иностранном происхождении  ,а в наше время не стоит фантазировать. Если я Вас обидел,то прошу меня извинить.

Comment: БОГАТЫРЬ

БОГАТЫРЬ м. татарск. человек рослый, дородный, дюжий и видный; необычайный силач; смелый и удачливый, храбрый и счастливый воин, витязь. http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AB%D0%A0%D0%AC/  Влади́мир Ива́нович Даль (10 [22] ноября 1801 — 22 сентября [4 октября] 1872) — русский учёный, писатель и лексикограф, составитель «Толкового словаря живого великорусского языка».

Comment: К теме это как не относилось, так и не относится. Что касается Даля, то и на старуху, как известно, проруха найдется.

Comment: Немного странный диалог, обсуждаются сразу две темы: суффикс ЫРЬ и происхождение слова "богатырь". Богатырь присутствует в древнерусском языке уже в 10 веке в форме "богатуръ" со значением "витязь, герой". Происхождение восточное, оно известно в тюркских языках и в языках иранской группы,его значение "смелый, храбрый,отважный". (Этот материал взят из словаря Черных). Можно предположить, что изменения окончания  объясняется влиянием других  подобных слов с предметным значением, в которых ЫРЬ является суффиксом или входит в основу.

Comment: Суффикс ЫРЬ выделяется в современном языке, его значение указано в словаре.  Для образования нового  слова используется ОСНОВА мотивирующего слова, а не какие-то формы слова, так что никакие фантазии вида "красив - красивырь" к словообразованию отношения не имеют. Этимология некоторых слов бывает неясной, иногда существуют варианты. В любом случае, если вы не специалист по этимологии, лучше использовать известные источники. Если водлый - волдырь неверно, укажите варианты из других словарей,которым вы доверяете.

Comment: Добавлю простонародных слов с суффиксом -ырь : булдырь, немтырь, хмырь, супырь, колдырь, понырь, ходырь... Слово *сударь* в народе произносилось очень часто в виде *судырь*.

Comment: ды вы все уперлись в суффиксы, а это искусственное понятие, насажденное лингвистами.И все таки  это корни, сильно поврежденные как дурным произношением, так и временем. Потому и надо рассматривать суффиксы, как корни, а не приставку к слову, без всякого смысла. и связывать это надо не с исключительно влиянием первого попавшегося на ум совпадения. Богатырь-рыцарь, а он участвует в турнирах-схватках, не в цирковом представлении, а в бою...ЭТО ТУР. А бог, потому что божий человек--монах.  ПЕРЕСВЕТ, ОСЛЯБЯ,   монахи богатыри. и решался исход по божьей воле, кому бог помогал, так именно считали.

Comment: не влезло, см. ответ

Answer (score 0):

Водла ж. твер. важность. Водлый, важный. Водлужь? ж. -жье ср. (вдоль?) арх. место в теле, в мясе, где много сухожилья: | суковатое и свилеватое место в дереве (сомнительно).

Это у Даля.
благополучно устарело,  скорее от водить, и от воды в конечном итоге.

Водлужь? это искажение от ветлуж--ветлуга - разветвление. На севере и говор--поморский, отдельный словарь надо. У Даля такого не было.

булдырь, немтырь, хмырь, супырь, колдырь, понырь, ходырь

Булдырь. I булды́рь I. "нарыв, шишка, прыщ"-волдырь---очевидна замена букв.
интересно как оно в действии, если надавить,  дырка и все что там, булькает на землю. Какой такой суффикс? еще топоним в Татарии-Булгарии, на карту глянешь, хороший суффикс на карте, а?
немтырь-немой  тоже суффикс? а букву т с потолка взяли? да немой руками разговаривает--тырит-тащит и показывает что это и как.

хмырь--блатное,  наркоман. опустившийся человек.
хмуро-если ломка.

супырь супы́рь м. "надутый, брюзгливый, недоступный человек" (Даль). От *sǫ- и* руr- в пы́рить "топорщить" (см.). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973
тут еще и носопырка, нос вздернутый, оттопыренный.

колдырь--так это современный слэнг,связано с пьянкой и коктейлями, от cold drink   у молодежи сплошь заимствования, оно и понятно, знания языка поверху.  а у Даля в словаре такого нету и до перестройки не было.

Понырь (Понырье, Понырья) — река в России, протекает в Бокситогорском районе Ленинградской области. Правый приток реки Воложба, бассейн Сяси.
Поныри--топоним.

ходыри--топонимы, а ходырь такого слова нет. Фамилия есть  Ходырев.
суффиксами и тут не пахнет.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ Софье на "Происхождение восточное, оно известно в тюркских языках и в языках иранской группы, его значение "смелый, храбрый, отважный". (Этот материал взят из словаря Черных)".
Мой ответ взят из книги русского историка Д.И. Иловайского "Начало Руси" из главы "О славянском происхождении дунайских болгар" VII параграфа "Филологические приемы турко- и финноманов. Разбор некоторых личных имен и отдельных слов" стр.273-274: "12. Алогоботур, один из военачальников царя Симеона. Это имя передано византийцами не совсем точно: настоящее его произношение, конечно, есть Алобоготур. Совершенно такую же перестановку встречаем мы у Симеона Логофета: вместо Богорис он пишет Гоборис. Албоготур есть, конечно, слово сложное из ал или ар, и боготур или богатырь. Следовательно мы имеем здесь прозвание вроде Яртура Всеволода в Слове о полку Игореве".
И далее ученый делает примечание следующего характера: "Почему-то у нас существует мнение, что слово богатырь не славянского происхождения, а заимствовано нами у Татар, и в доказательство приводят, что до татарского владычества оно не встречается в письменных памятниках. Но, во-первых, есть множество других слов, несомненно употреблявшихся народом и случайно не попавших в немногие дошедшие до нас памятники дотатарской эпохи. Во-вторых, слова бог и тур несомненно славянские; почему же, будучи сложены вместе, они дадут татарское слово? В-третьих, слово богатырь есть у западных Славян, то есть у Поляков и Чехов. А приведенное здесь имя болгарского военачальника показывает, что это слово задолго до татарского владычества существовало и у южных Славян. Следовательно объяснение его татарским влиянием было основано на недостаточном изучении. Мне уже случалось указывать на то, что у нас продолжает господствовать очевидная наклонность всякое слово, сколько-нибудь трудное для объяснения, толковать иноземным влиянием, и что в лексике татаро-финских народов много общего с лексиконом народов арийских, особенно восточно-славянских. Не надо забывать исконное и тесное соседство этих народов еще в древней Скифии и средней Азии. Следовательно, лексикон той и другой группы народов отражает влияние времен еще доисторических, и скорее можно предположить влияние арийских народов, как более одаренных и ранее развившихся, на соседние народы северной, или урало-монгольской группы".

Comment: Антон, старайтесь не использовать "ответы" для комментариев ответов других участников. Для этого здесь есть комментарии.